# Why is it not allowed to use self when creating a property using closure?

Tags: swift, delegates, closures, self

```
// Design Protocol
protocol SendDataDelegate {}

// Design Sender/Delegator
class SendingVC {
    var delegate: SendDataDelegate?
    
    deinit {
        print("Delegator gone")
    }
}

// Design Receiver/Delegate
class ReceivingVC: SendDataDelegate {
    lazy var sendingVC: SendingVC = { // if i don't use lazy, i am not allowed to use self within the closure.
        let vc = SendingVC()
        vc.delegate = self // here
        return vc
    }()
    
    deinit {
        print("Delegate gone")
    }
}
```

What is the reason behind this?
From what i found online: Since the object is not initialised the self is not available, what does that even mean?

Comment: `self` just refers to the object itself, in its entirety. Your object still hasn't gone through its initializer which means it's not yet complete. Once an object is complete (after it has completed its own lifecycle), then `self` becomes available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means exactly what it says.

- If you do not say `lazy`, then with your equal sign (`=`) you are trying to initialize `sendingVC`, an instance property of ReceivingVC, while a ReceivingVC instance itself (`self`) is being initialized. Mentioning `self` during its own initialization is circular so it's forbidden.
- By saying `lazy`, you are saying: do not initialize `sendingVC` until sometime *after* the ReceivingVC instance (`self`) has been initialized — namely, when some other code refers to it. That solves the problem and mentioning `self` is now allowed.